# Process an Asynchronous Iterator in background

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I trying to process an asynchronous iterator in background.

I can process in the main function:

```py
target = ...
async def main():
  async for item in target.listen():
    print(item) # works fine

  print('done') # never arrives, because loop iterates forever

asyncio.run(main())
```

But doing it this way, the code is blocking.

So I try process the iterator in other function with create_task, but the loop never iterates.

```py
target = ...
async def process():
  async for item in target.listen():
    print(item) # never print

async def main():
  asyncio.create_task(process())
  print('done') # works

asyncio.run(main())
```

Is it possible to process an asynchronous iterator in background? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `create_task()` and then immediately exit -- which is what you're doing in your code -- then of course the task never runs. You can only run something "in the background" if you're doing something in the foreground, and you're not.

Even if your `main` function wasn't exiting immediately, your background task still wouldn't run. Asyncio provides *concurrent* execution, but not *parallel* execution -- other tasks won't execute unless the current task yields control by calling `await`.

Here's a working example; I've replaced your `target` variable with a simple list of words just so we have something over which to iterate:

```
import asyncio

target = "one two three four five six".split()


async def process():
    for item in target:
        print(item)  # never print
        await asyncio.sleep(0.3)


async def main():
    task = asyncio.create_task(process())
    while not task.done():
        print("doing something while waiting")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("done")


asyncio.run(main())
```

Running the above code produces:

```
doing something while waiting
one
two
three
four
doing something while waiting
five
six
done
```

---

Rather than checking for `task.done()` as I've done in this example, you would in practice be more likely to use one of the [waiting primitives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#waiting-primitives) or [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently) to wait for the completion of background tasks.